# Same function works on one code but not on other

Tags: javascript

I have a function should make one div "first" disappear and make another "second" appear. I know I can do this with Jquery, but would prefer to do it with vanilla JS. This is a list of posts, each with an edit button. The edit button calls the function and the "second" div appears with the same data albeit as pre-filled form field values ready for editing.

I made an analogous setup in codepen that works, but in my project it doesn't. Can anybody see why?

from codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vegdzO

```
   <div class='square' style='height: 200px; width: 200px; background: 
   red;'>PARENT

  <div class='lil-square' style='height: 100px;      width: 100px; 
  background: green; margin: 20px;' onclick='openEdit(this)'>CHILD</div>   
  </div>

  <div class='square' style='height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue; 
  display: none;'>NEXT SIBLING  

  </div>
```

JS:

```
  function openEdit(element) 
  {
   element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';

   element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

from my project:

```
    <?php
    foreach($sessions as $index)
            {       
            echo "<div class='wrap'>
                    <div class='well session' id='first'> 
                            Date: ".$index['session_date']."<br>
                            Trainer: ".$index['trainer']."<br>
                            Clinic: <a class='clinic-link' title='Click to see clinic sessions'>".$index['org']."</a><br>
                            Duration: ".$index['duration']." hours <br> <br>                                     
                            Note: ".$index['session_note']."<br><br>
                            <a class='btn btn-lg btn-default edit' class='edit-button' onclick='openEdit(this)'>Edit</a>
                    </div>                 

                    <div class='well edit-form' id='second'>
                            <form>
                                    <label for='session_edit_date'>Date:</label> 
                                            <input type='date' name='session_edit_date' id='session_edit_date' value='".$index['session_date']."'><br>
                                    <label for='session_edit_trainer'>Trainer:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='session_edit_trainer' id='session_edit_trainer' value='".$index['trainer']."'><br>
                                    <label for='session_edit_clinic'>Clinic:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='session_edit_clinic' id='session_edit_clinic' value='".$index['org']."'><br>
                                    <label for='session_edit_duration'>Duration:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='session_edit_duration' id='session_edit_duration' value='".$index['duration']."'><br>
                                    <label for='session_edit_note'>Note:</label>
                                            <input type='textarea' name='session_edit_note' id='session_edit_note' value='".$index['session_note']."'><br>  
                            </form> 
                    </div> 
                    </div> ";
            }
    ?>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
    function openEdit(element) {
    element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';    
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: In what way does this "not work"?  The HTML produced by your PHP code seems a bit more involved than what's in your CodePen.  What is the actual HTML you're using when the problem occurs?

Comment: Strategically placed `debugger` and `console.log` statements may be helpful. For example, how sure are you that `element.parentNode` references the element you actually want to hide/show? Who knows... a missing end tag somewhere earlier in the DOM could be causing problems. Since you've already got ids on the target divs, why not just select by id?

Comment: I guess what I mean is that the HTML/PHP code produces the desired output without the function. But the function, applied to the 'edit' button does not work by affecting the parent and next sibling of parent, as it does in the codepen example. The function is the same in both cases.

Comment: @JDB I can't select by id, because this code is generated as the HTML around PHP data fetched dynamically from the DB, so the ids won't be unique, or if they were, I can't know what they will be. I've checked in the console and confirmed that I'm targeting the right elements with parentNode and ParentNode.nextElementSibling

Comment: Well, id attributes _should_ be unique. But, that said, you've got a reference to `$index` already... so set the id to `id='first_".$index['id']."'"` and then pass along the session id to your function... `onclick='openEdit(this,"'.$index['id'].'")'`

Comment: @Argut: If I put your second HTML into your same CodePen, replace your PHP output with dummy values, and set your target "sibling" element to `display:none;` by default then your code works exactly as expected: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxpVMJ  It's not clear at all what the actual problem is.

Comment: Then your function becomes `function openEdit(element,sessionId) {` and then you can select the correct div by its id.

Comment: @JDB interesting solution..I will try that and let you know. Have limited time now, so will try all suggested options in a few hours. Thank you!

Comment: @David, I rewrote parts of my code, and without really knowing what the problem was, it started "half working". By this I mean the edit button brings forward the id="second" edit form, but a new 'close' button does not do the reverse as intended (close the edit form and reopen the post). This is related, but is a new subject. If I ask another question, should I reference this one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what change solved this. My original code was ok...I just rewrote parts and it worked, so it was a fluke error. Please delete the post if it's of no use to anyone, and thank you to everyone who offered help.